# Overflow pow function with long long?

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem defining a pow function for long long values, this is the code:

```
long long int pow( long long int base, long long int exp){
    long long int count = 1;
    for(int i=exp; i>=0; i--){
        if(i==0) {break;}
        if(exp==1) {count = count * base; break;}
        count = count * base;
    }
    return count;
}
```

it is necessary to use iteration and not to be recursive, if I print the function for 2^i for I up to 63 from a certain moment on it computes 0, it is an overflow error? how can I avoid it?

Comment: At what moment it computes 0? What is the sizeof a long long int in your platform?

Comment: @pinotto This initialization of an object of the type int int i=exp in the for loop does not make a sense. You need to use long long int.

Comment: Assuming a `long long int` is 8 bytes on your system, you can represent all integers in the range `[-2^63, 2^63 - 1]`. So it'd make sense that 2^62 computes just fine but 2^63 overflows and gives you a large negative number. An easy test would be to print `pow(2, 63) - 1` and see if that gives you a positive number again (which would be the largest int you can represent with a `long long`).

Comment: @scohe001 assuming undefined behavior behaves in a defined way, which it usually does in this case ;)

Comment: @largest signed integer overflow has defined behavior in C++20 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Try using `double` instead of integers.  The [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function is for floating point.

Comment: Nitpicking: `for (int i = exp; i >= 0; i--) { if (i == 0) break; ...` could be written as `for (int i = exp; i > 0; i--) {`. Not to mention the `if(exp==1) {count = count * base; break;}`...

Comment: You also have to check if `exp` is negative, where you have to return `1 / pow(base, -exp)`